# Friendly URL vs ugly querystring URL SharePoint, HTTPModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, httpmodule

I am developing an application in SharePoint 2010.

What now I have to resolve is the following:
I have a list of news. Each one has an ID and Title.

I have one SharePoint page that knows how to display them.

I need that instead of linking each news as:
http://sharepoint/news/viewnews.aspx?title=MySharePointNews01

Be as the following:
http://sharepoint/news/MySharePointNews01

I think tha writing an HttpModule and doing Server.Transfer to the Viewnews.aspx will accomplish this.

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the IIS URL Rewrite module.  It will do exactly what you are looking for without having to write any code.  This article explains it pretty clear:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

You can download IIS URL Rewrite here:  http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite